# With Python's multiprocessing.Pool and map_asynch, how can I get information about the workers?

Tags: python, multiprocessing, threadpool

In the following program how can I check periodically:

- the number tasks which have to be yet started
- the number of workers currently working
- the number of tasks which have been finished
- the status for them (if they have timed out)

Code is:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
import time

def f(x):
    time.sleep(x)
    return x*x

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pool = Pool(processes=4)              # start 4 worker processes

    ar = pool.map_async(f, range(10))          # prints "[0, 1, 4,..., 81]"
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
    ar.wait()
    print ar.get()
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you wanted?

```
 ar._number_left
```

Comment: Can you get information about what has failed to complete (such as time out) ?